# a little help in figuring out htaccess rules and why they aren't working correctly

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have these rules and I can't figure out why one of them won't work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -MultiViews
Options -Indexes

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#RewriteRule ^error/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)$ /pages/error.php?$1=$2 [NC,R]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ index.php?user=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/.* index.php?$0 [PT]
RewriteRule ^error/.* error.php/?$0 [PT]
```

Rule 1 works, `echo $_GET['user']` then I get results

Rule 2 works as well. If I do a `print_r($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])` then I get what ever is after `.com/`.

so That makes me think that its catching correctly, and if I do a as well.

So those rules seem to be working... but now if I enter

`domain.com/error/access/notallowed` then I get a `Not Found` error, so that means that my Rule 3 that wants to catch anything that starts with `error` isn't working.

Any ideas on what may be causing this behavior?

EDIT: updated rules based on answer

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ index.php?user=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/error/?
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?.* index.php?$1 [PT]
RewriteRule ^(error/?.*)$ /_msp/pages/error.php/?$1
```

Comment: Here's a really helpful way to [test your rewrite rules](http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/) ...

Comment: wow cool tool, but still i can't get my rules to be reached! Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your second RewriteRule is catching `domain.com/error/access/notallowed` before apache is able to make it to the third RewriteRule. So, apache says, *"I've got a rule that matches, I'm finished here,"* and throws away the rest of your RewriteRules. If only there were a way we could tell apache to ignore the second rule in specific cases ...

### Say hello to RewriteCond

*"Wait, are you saying what I think you're saying? I can tell apache to ignore that second rule?"*

*"Yes, that's exactly what I'm saying."*

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ index.php?user=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/error/?
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?.* index.php?$1 [PT]
RewriteRule ^(error/.*)$ index.php?$1 [PT]
```

See that **RewriteCond** line just before your second rule? You can insert any number of conditions and they will apply to the next evaluated rule. So, in this specific RewriteCond we're telling apache that the following rule shouldn't be used if the REQUEST_URI starts with `/error/`.

The rewritten URL using the above rules for the address `domain.com/error/access/notallowed` will be:

`index.php/?error/access/notallowed`

You can adjust the regex according to your needs.

Comment: i added your rules and this is the test site for you to see the actual results. `http://msp.eli007.com` `msp.eli007.com/s2xi` works, `msp.eli007.com/error` works (returns the ?user=$1 rule) but the `msp.eli007.com/error/access/notallowed` does not catch. I edited my post to reflect the htaccess change

Comment: the _msp folder is in the root where I am assuming it part of the `RewriteBase` points to. And yes, the error.php is there.

Comment: woops, left off a very important `!` at the beginning of the RewriteCond when I typed it in -- lemme know if that fixes your issue.

Comment: i applied the new rules, you can test them out. but the results are the same. I still find it weird how some rules work but the others don't, is it because its looking for a directory?

Comment: Is it possible that you have an .htaccess file anywhere in `_msp/pages` that could be overriding the rules set out in the base .htaccess file?

Comment: i thought of that too, i made sure there was no htaccess files anywhere, but i also tried the index.php instead of the error.php to make sure the rules worked.

Comment: i'll try it on a different server, maybe there is correlation

Comment: I'm not sure how the slash crept in after index.php in `RewriteRule ^(error/?.*)$ index.php/?$1 [PT]` but that's likely the problem. I wasn't testing with it ... stupid typo ... wasted half an hour of both of our time. *Anyway*, that should fix the issue and I updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: missed you on chat, sorry. I appreciate your help, I have done this before and am new to the [PT] usage and thru that i found out that I can't even catch the error segment. thats what frustrates me when something used to work and won't work in another instance.

Comment: if you run your examples through this website do you get positive results? `http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/`

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you switch the last two it should work:

```
RewriteRule ^error/.* error.php/?$0 [PT]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/.* index.php?$0 [PT]
```

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/.* index.php?$0 [PT] rule is matching the url, I believe rewriting it and passing it through as the index.php, but I am not a htaccess expert.